# Isometries of hyperbolic 3-space!

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry

The Klein model of the hyperbolic 3-space is defined as follows

$$\mathbb{H}^3=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^{3,1}:\langle x,x\rangle_{3,1}<0\}/\sim$$

where  $x\sim x'$ if and only there exists $\lambda$ such that $x =\lambda x' $, and $\mathbb{R}^{3,1}$ is the (3+1)-Minkowski space.

My question: What is the group of isometries in this case?

Thank You.

Comment: It should be $PGL_2(\mathbb{C})$, or equivalently something like $O^{+}(3, 1)$, see http://www.maths.qmul.ac.uk/~sb/LTCCcourse/Holodyn2013notes_week3.pdf .